# How could return map<int, variant>'s value by a function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++17, variant

I want to have a map to save different types of value, so I have a map like

```
std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>> m ={{1,1},{2,"asd"}};
```

And Now I want to design a function to get the value by its key like

```
auto get(int key) {
    ...
    return value;
}
```

That's to say what I want is like

```
get(1) -> 1
get(2) -> "asd"
```

So is it possible? If so what's the exact solution?

---

**ADDED**:

Yes, as for the purpose of the design, I want to save config datas reading from config files.

And after reading I need to make some type changing or data transform.
Such as in config files like

```
a=1
b=asd
```

And after reading it, I want to save it as
m["a"]=int(3) ---->refers `a=1` and needs to plus 2 after reading  its actual data `1`
m["b"]=std::string("asdasd") ---->refers `b=asd` and needs to double it

So I think it will be easier if there is an interface function to get the exact value by the key

Comment: The types are fixed at compile-time. Your function must return a variant.

Comment: unless you wanted `get(1)` and `get(2)` to return different types, I don't understand the question. The values are of type `std::variant<int,std::string>>` so you can return that

Comment: C++ does not work this way. Your function can only return a `std::variant<int, std::string>`. The only alternative is for your function to be a template that takes a callable object, as a parameter, that gets fed to `std::visit`.

Comment: It is probably best to find another way to accomplish your goal. Returning different types can be troublesome, and very inefficient.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  See [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: What is the purpose behind this?  Is it to store some kind of configuration data?

Comment: A word of wisdom: don't do it. For best performance have 2 separate maps instead; one for `int` one for `string`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thx first, and I try to demonstate my purpose in addition, and hopefully for more help to solve.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thx first, and I try to demonstate my purpose in addition, and hopefully for more help to solve.

Comment: Personally, I store all my config data as strings.  If I want to treat it as a number, I convert it.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

A) You want to return either `int` or `std::string` depending on the index passed to the function.

Not possible. A function has one return type. Also `auto` is not magic. If you cannot write the actual type, then the compiler can't either.

B) You want to return the `mapped_type` of the map.

You can return `std::variant<int, std::string>` from the function.

---

Your `get` can't do much "better" than `std::variant::get`. With `std::variant::get` you need to specify at compile time what type you want to retrieve. And there is no way around that if you want to get either `int` or `std::string`.

---

There might be better ways to solve your actual issue, the one for which you thought `auto get(int key)` was the solution. A comment (by Eljay) mentions [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). There you can see a couple of examples of how to deal with variants.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot exactly design a function with this syntax. Just imagine this:

```
int key = 0;
if (rand() % 2) {
    key = 1;
} else {
    key = 2;
}

auto value = get(key);
```

Here's the riddle:

> Please tell me the return type of `get` and the type of `value`. There can be only one answer and you can only answer with a single type that will remain unchanging no matter how much time I ask you this question.

If you can't answer, well, the compiler cannot either.

However, it doesn't mean you can't design something similar that will do what you need.

You could just return the variant. This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's worth noting since it doesn't change any of the input of the `get` function.

You can also just send the expected type:

```
get<int>(key)
```

The implementation would look like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto get(int key) -> T {
    return std::get<int>(m[key]);
}
```

If you cannot know the expected type, then you could just send a visitor:

```
get(key, [](auto value) -> std::size_t {
    if constexpr (std::same_as<int, decltype(value)>) {
        // do stuff with value as an int since it's a int here
        return value + 1;
    } else {
        // do stuff with value as a string since it's a string here
        return value.size(); 
    }
});
```

The implementation would look like this:

```
auto get(int key, auto visitor) -> decltype(auto) {
    return std::visit(visitor, m[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the requirements, you could return a proxy object from `get` that keeps a reference to the `variant` and depending on what you do with the proxy object, it can adapt. Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    using variant = std::variant<int, std::string>;

    // the proxy object
    struct proxy {
        // assignment:
        template<class T>
        variant& operator=(T&& value) {
            *data = std::forward<T>(value);
            return *data;
        }

        // for static_cast to the wanted type
        explicit operator int& () { return std::get<int>(*data); }
        explicit operator std::string& () { return std::get<std::string>(*data); }

        variant* data;
    };

    proxy get(int key) {
        // return the proxy object
        return proxy{&m[key]};
    }

    std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>> m = {{1,1}, {2,"asd"}};
};
```

And it could be used like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo f;
    
    // you need to know what it stores:
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(f.get(1)) << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(f.get(2)) << '\n';

    // assigning is simple:
    f.get(1) = "hello world"; // was int, now std::string
    f.get(2) = 2;             // was std::string, now int

    std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(f.get(1)) << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(f.get(2)) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: hm... not really different from returning the `std::variant` and then call `get` on the variant. Though, OP seems to want their runtime `get` for some reason, and this is a way to realize it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I agree. Proxies can be useful sometimes. I'm not 100% sure this is one of those times, but perhaps OP finds some ideas in it